# Google Analytics Report showing events per country

Tags: google-analytics, report

Is it possible to create a report to show which events happened per country ? :

example:
peru
     app started  2
chile 
     app started  5
usa
     app started  6

Answer (score 7):

In your standard reports, you can go to Behaviour > Events > Top Events, and then add a secondary dimension of Country/Territory.